# How does the "methylamine test for sugars" work exactly?

Tags: organic-chemistry, color, carbohydrates

There is a test that enables distinction of sugars between mono- and oligosachharides. 
It consists letting methylamine react with an aqueous solution of the sugar under alkalic conditions and elevated (~70°) temperature. 
Monosachharides always produce a yellow color; reducing oligosaccharides a red one and nonreducing sugars no coloration.

I wondered how this reaction works and of what "kind"/structure the resulting dyes might be.